# LTspice gives me strange wave form when I choose from 9.995s to 10s

Tags: ltspice

Here is the diagram.
[image]

Here is the strange wave form given by Ib(Q1)
[image]

The following is the Spice netlist

```
* G:\document\LTspice\multi_stage.asc
C1 N005 in 1µ
R1 N001 N005 47k
R2 N005 0 10k
R3 N001 N002 4.7k
R4 N006 0 1k
Q1 N002 N005 N006 0 myBJT
Q2 N004 N003 N007 0 myBJT
R5 N003 N001 47k
R6 N003 0 10k
R7 N001 N004 4.7k
R8 N007 0 1k
C2 N006 0 100µ
C3 N003 N002 1µ
C4 N007 0 100µ
C5 N004 out 1µ
V1 in 0 SINE(0 1u 314)
V2 N001 0 10
.model NPN NPN
.model PNP PNP
.lib C:\Users\hello\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.bjt
.tran 0 10 9.995 uic
.model myBJT AKO: BC547B (BF=150)
.meas vmax max V(out)
.meas vmin min V(out)
.meas vpp pp V(out)
.meas V1 PP V(in)
.meas V2 PP V(out)
.meas Gain param V2/V1
.meas I6 pp I(R6)
.meas I5 pp I(R5)
.meas Ix pp I(C3)
.meas Ib2 pp Ib(Q2)
.meas total param I5+I6+Ib2
.meas Ib1 pp Ib(Q1);
.meas Ic1 pp Ic(Q1);
.meas beta param Ic1/Ib1
.backanno
.end
```

Why do we have the red part at the beginning part the wave in the following picture?
[image]

I got the following picture when I use `.tran 0 10 9.995 1u uic`

[image]

Comment: It's a simple circuit, maybe use a Vero board and a real oscilloscope?

Comment: @NaturalDemon Unfortunately, I don't have the equipment needed to do this experiment now in my room.

Comment: Changing the max time step does nothing to ameliorate the problem?

Comment: @kile I payed 40€ for my first (Philips) scope. it's old, but still does the job despite the beam being a bit out of focus.

Comment: Try taking out uic (skip initial operating point solution) in your simulation command

Comment: Try this **.tran 0 10 9.995 1u** (your time step is too small for such a low current. I guess)

Comment: @G36 I can't add 1u but I can successfully add `.tran 0 10 9.995 10000 uic`.
However, the result is the same

Comment: Why can't you set the maximum time step? Also, why do you enable uic?

Comment: @G36 I finally did what you suggested but it's still weird. see my updated picture. The reson why I enable uic because I want to make initial voltage of this system is 0 volts for both AC and DC

Comment: Like others have mentioned, don't use `uic`.  Use `startup` instead, which is the first checkbox option in the `.tran` settings window.

Comment: @SteKulov What's the differences between`uic` and `statup`

Comment: See my answer here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/652838/254890

Comment: If you're still having problems, try disabling waveform compression by adding this SPICE directive to your schematic:  `.options plotwinsize=0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has something to do with the integration method. Trapezoidal and modified Trapezoidal will give the odd glitch when *uic* or *startup* are used in the .tran card. 
If you use **Gear** integration method, the circuit behaves as you expect. Select the integration method in Tools -> Control Panel ->  SPICE.

As stated in the comments below the original question:

1. Removing the uic or startup condition solves the issue.
2. Making the time step smaller in the .tran card is helpful. 100us helps, but not quite perfect; 10us looks pretty good.

Good practice with SPICE, do not leave floating nodes in SPICE as you have done with C5.

Comment: I recommend against setting the integration method to Gear within the control panel since that setting persists (denoted by the asterisk) until you change it back, and Gear generally causes more problems than Modified Trap.  For problematic schematics which require Gear, I suggest adding a `.options method=gear` SPICE directive to the particular schematic in question to force the change only on that schematic.