# Step response v/s DC voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, control, basic, transient, simulink

I have to find step response for this circuit considering my input as Vo and step for Vin( I am using Simulink for this)
[image]

Firstly what i did was making this circuit (DC voltage is 1V)
[image]

The response on Voltage scope was :
[image]

What i was expecting a underdamped response

Then i looked up on youtube and saw this arrangement:
[image]

This gave the exact result that i was expecting
[image]

I kind of read it on internet that DC analysis assumes that the signal existed even before t=0 and step goes to 1 exactly at t=0.

Could someone explain in a little detail.
Also, how do i perform DC analysis via transfer function between Vo and Vin?
Also, is there something Simulink specific that i don't know.

Thanks

Comment: In the first case, simulation normally goes through an initial step to solve the DC operating point. It did that and gave you what it worked out. The voltage supply didn't change or make a step. So you got an obvious result. In the more complex case, something was added to force a changing event. Which is what you'd really wanted. There are still other and less complicated ways to do that -- such as using the UIC modifier to the .tran card.

Answer (score 1):

A causal input signal \$u(t)\$ is zero for \$t<0\$.

If there is an input prior to zero, then the system has already responded to that input. In other words the state variables have initial conditions.

A constant (for all time) input \$U\$ can be considered a step input whose \$t=0\$ happened a long time ago, so the system has already reached steady state.

> how do i perform DC analysis via transfer function between Vo and Vin?

Enter a transfer function into a transfer function block and apply a constant input.

Answer (score 0):

Your question felt to me a little bit `all over the place` in its focus. You provided a curve, but at first I wasn't sure if (a) that curve was an input you needed to analyze and find values for the schematic, or otherwise if (b) the schematic had already been provided (with values you don't show) and that you were told what to expect and couldn't get that to happen from Spice.

I mentioned in comments that you can just use the UIC modifier to the .TRAN card. (All Spice programs support this.) I talk about it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/652816/330261). All it does is prevent Spice from performing an `initial transient solution` (ITS) step before starting with \$t=0\$.

There are two choices when Spice is asked to start a run and where no initial conditions for inductors and capacitors are given:

1. **Either** first work out the DC operating point at \$t=0\$, setting the initial conditions for inductors and capacitors based upon that analysis, and then start the simulation once that's handled. This is very useful for transistor circuits, which often have AC coupling capacitors and DC biasing networks. In this case, the user is more likely focused on seeing signal voltage gains and they don't want to sit around watching all the capacitors gradually charge up to their quiescent points. This is the default case for Spice -- performing the ITS first in order to work out all the DC biasing issues and to set up capacitors and inductors to their default quiescent, but not necessarily zero, conditions. And then letting the simulation run with input signals applied.
2. **Or** do ***not*** work out the DC operating point at \$t=0\$, but instead set all of the initial voltages across capacitors to zero and the initial currents in inductors to zero (except for any that have the .IC card given, specifying their values), and with those assumptions and/or .IC specifications just start the simulation at \$t=0\$ and let things gravitate towards their quiescent values over time. This is the situation you get with the **UIC** added to the .TRAN card.

So in your case that's what you probably wanted to use so that you got case (2) above, not case (1).

Your circuit is a 2nd order low-pass, of course, with \$K=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$, \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{L_1\,C_1}}\$, and \$Q=\frac1{R_1\,\mid\mid\,R_2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{L_1}{C_1}}\$.

It didn't take a genius to figure out that your \$Q=2\$ and that \$K=\frac12\$. And from the 2% settling time (\$4\tau\$), which seemed about like \$16\:\text{s}\$ to me, and the fact that in this case \$Q=2\omega_{_0}\$, I knew that \$\omega_{_0}=1\$.

So \$K=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}=\frac12\$, \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\sqrt{L_1\,C_1}}=1\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$, and \$Q=\frac1{R_1\,\mid\mid\,R_2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{L_1}{C_1}}=2\$. The only way that happens is if \$R_1=R_2=L_1\$ and \$\left(R_1=R_2=L_1\right)\cdot C_1=1\$. Clearly, I can just set \$R_1=R_2=1\:\Omega\$, \$L_1=1\:\text{H}\$, and \$C_1=1\:\text{F}\$. (Though other combinations are possible.)

It would have been easier if you'd just said so, though, and disclosed the part values you were using.

Anyway, here's what LTspice does:

[image]

Note the red underline highlighting my use of the **UIC** parameter with the .TRAN card.

All the above is just to let you know how it can be done using any Spice program you might encounter. Your program includes some special widgets. And you are free to use them. But they won't always be found in every Spice program. (*Not* in LTspice, for example.) But **UIC** is supported by all Spice programs. So it is a good idea to learn about it.